# SQL cannot export json file from 2 SQL queries

Tags: json, sql-server, bcp

I have this stored procedure where I export some data from a SQL Server table to json file.

It works all fine when I only have one SQL query which makes sense because it exports only one json file.

But what I want to do is create two json files from two SQL Server tables from a single procedure...

Right now my stored procedure (working) looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PopulateJsonFiles]
AS 
    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @FileName varchar(500)

    SET @FileName = '\\C:\Projects\JsonFiles\Sqltable1.json'
    SET @sql = 'bcp "' + 
    'select * from Sqltable1'+
        --if I add this line down it breaks the procedure and exports nothing :( 
        'select * from [Audit]'+

    ' FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES" ' +
    'queryout  "'+@FileName+ '"' + 
    ' -c -S myMachine -d myDatabase-T'

    EXEC sys.XP_CMDSHELL @sql
GO
```

So right now it only works if I only write `'select * from Sqltable1'+` but now if I put another select statement in it.

I get that it runs into a conflict with the name because this way will try to create two documents with the same name, but how can I escape this and create two separate files with different names maybe?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Have you tried executing the query `select * from Sqltable1select * from [Audit] FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` in SSMS? Does it give you a syntax error because it doesn't know what `Sqltable1select` is? Seems like you'll want to execute bcp.exe seperately if you want seperate files.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you calling `cmd` batch from T-SQL which calls `bcp` with a T-SQL batch? Why not execute from `cmd` directly? And to be honest, you should probably do this in Powershell, which is much better for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this so I am posting just in case someone might need this in the future too.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PopulateJsonFiles]
AS 
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
DECLARE @FileName varchar(500)

--for the first table and first file 
SET @FileName = '\\C:\Projects\JsonFiles\Sqltable1.json'
SET @sql = 'bcp "' + 
'select * from Sqltable1'+
' FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES" ' +
'queryout  "'+@FileName+ '"' + 
' -c -S myMachine -d myDatabase-T'
EXEC sys.XP_CMDSHELL @sql

--for the second table and second file
SET @FileName = '\\C:\Projects\JsonFiles\Sqltable2.json'
SET @sql = 'bcp "' + 
'select * from Sqltable2'+
' FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES" ' +
'queryout  "'+@FileName+ '"' + 
' -c -S myMachine -d myDatabase-T'
EXEC sys.XP_CMDSHELL @sql
GO
```